# VimのHaskellプラグイン

Tags: vim, haskell

VimでHaskellを書いているものです。
なんらかのプラグインの影響だとは思いますが、表示が省略されるのをやめてほしいです。
例えば、
main = do
   hogehoge
のように書いたものが、Vimで開いた直後には
main = -------------------------------------
のように表示されます。カーソルを載せて動かすと詳細表示されます。
鬱陶しいのでやめさせたいです。
現状入れているプラグインについてすべて検索しましたが有益な情報は得られませんでした。
vimrcに記述されているプラグインは
Shougo/neobundle.vim'
cohama/lexima.vim
nanotech/jellybeans.vim
shougo/neocomplete.vim
kana/vim-filetype-haskell
eagletmt/ghcmod-vim
Shougo/neocomplcache
ujihisa/neco-ghc
thinca/vim-quickrun
Shougo/vimproc
dag/vim2hs
Shougo/vimshell
scrooloose/nerdtree
こんな感じでございます。
vimrcから記述を消したものもあります。

省略表示の直し方について回答お願いします。

Comment: Vim 上でコマンド `:verbose set foldmethod?` と `:verbose set foldexpr?` を実行して結果を追記して頂けるとより細かい回答がつくと思います．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set nofoldenable
```

でどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法で解決しました

Comment: @user24965 さん、お役に立てて幸いです。課題が解決できた場合は、解決に最も役立った回答に「承認」のチェックを入れるのがこのサイトのルールとなっております。課題解決後には必ず承認をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

どこかで foldlevelstart を設定していませんか? これを
set foldlevelstart=99
としておけば、ファイル・オープン時は折りたたみが開いた状態になります

これでダメなら、プラグインで上書きされているのが原因だと思うので、
autocmd FileType haskel setlocal foldlevelstart=99
等と autocmd と組み合わせれば、おそらく可能かと思います

Comment: 提示されている方法は試してみましたがだめでした...

Comment: > autocmd FileType haskel setlocal foldlevelstart=99

この場合、

autocmd FileType haskel setlocal foldlevel=99

にすべきでした